# Fox Pro Export Routine

Tags: perl, shell, export, foxpro

So in order to get DBF files from an old Fox Pro db, I have to use an OEM exe which splashes on my XPSP3 screens for a brief moment before delivering it's delicious DBF's.

I'm trying to wrap that guy up in an export program to run on the client, and I was wondering if there's any way (I've tried start /run min, wrapping it up in VB6 with vbhide (vb6..bleech!) I can run it hidden?

I know the window preferences are a request, and to give an idea of how ugly the OEM exe is - it appears to actually be calling another ugly OEM exe during its routine.  And I'm pretty sure it's that exe that's getting all the on-screen attention.

Other than running all this as a service, is there anyway to do this?  Might perl's Win32::GUI library handle "shelling" it hidden?

Comment: DBF files are old FoxPro databases...

Comment: Also, do you really mean OEM (original equipment manufacturer)?

Comment: DBF files are FoxPro, Clipper or even dBase tables. DBC/DCX/DCT files comprise a Visual FoxPro database.

Answer (score 1):

perl's Win32::GUI worked great!

Comment: [This](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=536260) helped me out good a bit, hope someone else as well-thanks,

Comment: You should accept this answer so other's can find the solution.